# Getting unexpected output using "fread"

Tags: c, file-io, struct, fread

Can anyone please help me solving the following code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char another= 'Y';
    struct emp
    {
        char name[14];
        int age;
        float bs;
    }e;
    fp = fopen("Employee.DAT", "wb");
        if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (another == 'Y')
    {
        printf("\nEnter name, age and basic salary:");
        scanf("%s %d %f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
        fwrite(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp);
        printf("Add another record?(Y/N)");

        another=_getche();
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to input the following:
`Abc 19 11111
Def 20 22222
Ghi 21 33333`
The output for the below code should be as the input of the above code but I'm getting the output for the below as in the image attached below:
[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct emp
    {
        char name[14];
        int age;
        float bs;
    }e;
    fp = fopen("Employee.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1);
    printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is with "fread" but I'm unable to find out the problem.

Comment: Did you check that the return value of fread is actually 1? Your print statement is outside of the while loop, so it'll be executed either way.

Comment: The `while` loop will only stop reading when `fread` read an invalid entry, and that – surprise! – is the one that will be printed. Delete the `;` at the end of that line.

Comment: I think you must close the file after writing. Also check your while loop and hence remove the ; after it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1);
printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
fclose(fp);
```

Your print statement is outside of the while loop, so it'll print only the last read information (or invalid, if no call to fread succeeded).

Indentation and blocks help to write correct code:

```
while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1) {
  printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
}
fclose(fp);
```

---

Also please note that this is not a good or reliable way to serialise data. The layout of the structure (and even is parts, look for endianness) may change between different compilers and architectures.

---

Also, you should close the file after writing it in the other code.

Comment: Thank you, I understood what you said.
; can seriously lead to suicidal output.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the semicolon after the while statement:

```
while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1) {
  printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
}
fclose(fp);
```

With the semicolon, the loop iterates through all the records and stops whenever no more records are present. Now the `printf()` print details of the recent(last) read record from file.

The code actually behaves as:

```
while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1)
    ;    
printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
fclose(fp);
```

**Also, please close the file soon after writing the records.**

Comment: Yes, I did but I missed that expression in this code as it was copy paste. The only problem was with ; at the end of while statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1);
 printf("%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
```

`printf` statement should be inside while loop. Remove `;` after while.`fread` will read till `end of file` that is till last record and `printf` after loop will print the last record .

Answer (score 1):

```
while (fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1);
```

Remove that semicolon from the loop and you are done !!!!